# How to Separate the Profile Details

Tags: iphone

I try to read education details from face book using JSON in IPhone.

I read all education details from Face book successfully.

But i get the whole details. I want to separate the school, college {PG and UG}. But the node having same name like school. and also the data wil be read first one school, and then read one college, then again read one school and read one college like that. somebody fill one school more than one college. somebody wil fill more than one school and one college, somebody wont fill school or college. some id having same number of schools and college. some id having different number of schools and college. So how to I identify the schools and  college details separately. Please if anybody having any idea please share with me.

MY Doubt is how to identify the schools, and college and then print schools and college separately...

My sample output as follows..

"education":
    [
            {
                    "school":
                    {
                        "id":110402725649312,
                        "name":"10th class"
                    },
                    "year":
                    {
                        "id":102356633142124,
                        "name":"2001"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "school":
                    {
                            "id":111983532181734,
                            "name":"Bsc Maths"
                    },
                    "year":
                    {
                            "id":146950445337693,
                            "name":"2006"
                    },
            },
            {
                    "school":
                    {
                            "id":115980035092981,
                            "name":"+2"
                    },
                    "year":
                    {
                            "id":114786038555902,
                            "name":"2003"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "school":
                    {
                            "id":130814456944277,
                            "name":"mca"
                    },
                    "year":
                    {
                            "id":115598488468394,
                            "name":"2010"
                    },
            }
}]

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to retrieve a school ID from Facebook based on the id field you're getting there, but I'm sure there's a way to traverse their Social Graph structure to find it.

The advice I have for you is: Use the [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to convert that into a native NSArray containing NSDictionaries. Then walking that data becomes a ton easier.